# Upload Pdf File in Mongodb using Django and AngularJs

Tags: django, mongodb, angularjs, file-upload

I want to add a feature of uploading file in my project , But I am confused of where to implement that code whether in django or AngularJS , even if I am doing that in AngularJs how to integrate that with django , I am extremely confused into this ,  Please suggest some links from where on I can start implementing , as I am not able to find one. Any suggestions would be appreciated..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hope some of the below links will helps you.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/1mgvqbXx43g

https://github.com/geersch/AngularJSFileUpload

http://jasonturim.wordpress.com/2013/09/12/angularjs-native-multi-file-upload-with-progress/